# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed using Bag of Words (BOW)

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I'm trying to use SURF with Bag Of Words in c++ but OpenCV is throwing an exception that I don't know how to solve it.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((globalDescIdx>=0) && (globalDescIdx < size())) in getLocalIdx, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp, line 163
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp:163: error: (-215) (globalDescIdx>=0) && (globalDescIdx < size()) in function getLocalIdx

The code works if I only read one image like the code bellow:

```
    cv::Mat img=imread("/home/cecilia/catkin_ws/src/self_driven_car/src/src/object_detection/images/Belgium/Training/0/images/image12.jpg",0);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;        
    detector->detect(img,keypoints);
    cv::Mat bowDescriptor;        
    bowDE.compute(img,keypoints,bowDescriptor);
```

However, if I try to read all images on my dataset, it throws the Assertion failed exception.

```
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
Mat bowDescriptor;
Mat trainingData(0, 61, CV_32FC1);
for(unsigned int i=0;i<files.size();i++){
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<files[i].size();j++){
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(files[i][j], 0);
            if (img.empty()){
                std::cerr << "WARNING: Could not read image." << std::endl;
                std::cerr << files[i][j] << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                detector->detect(img,keypoints);
                cv::Mat bowDescriptor;
                bowDE.compute(img,keypoints,bowDescriptor);
            }
```

Comment: You can try to verify in which one of the images in your dataset is causing the code to fail. Then we can try to move on and solve your problem :)

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to add that... It's not an specific image, sometimes it's in an image let's say, with an index = 12, other times it's with an index = 4 :( I already tried to read only the image that crashs the code and it also works. The last test that I did I tired to read one of the images that currently crashes 674 times (the total number of images on the dataset), it works for like 100 times and then crashes again :(.

Comment: But if you run in the same image, let's say "alone", does it fails?

Comment: yes... If I change the image in the piece of first code above... it works fine, the only problem is on the loop

Comment: Can you provide a minimum sample, so I can run on my machine and try to reproduce? Also, what's your OpenCV version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://answers.opencv.org/question/26327/throwing-exception-in-matching-function/